# SFTP file upload using CURL and PHP

Tags: php, curl, upload, sftp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to SFTP upload files from PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1767117/how-to-sftp-upload-files-from-php)

I have two files:

- upload.php
- data.csv (***around 1MB***)

---

Upload.php should connect using SFTP and CURL and then send the data.csv file to their server. I have been given a URL, username and password so I can log-in using SFTP.

---

Can anyone tell me the code I should use? **Unfortunately I have no real experience with CURL**.

Thanks,

Ryan

Comment: is data.csv being generated by upload.php? or is upload.php doing nothing but the upload? if it's nothing but the upload, why not simply use the proper command-line sftp client instead of having to hack together far too much php?

Comment: If it's really sftp (SSH File Transfer Protocol) would be better to use php ssh extension http://php.net/manual/en/book.ssh2.php

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SSH2](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.ssh2.php) extension:

```
$host = 'domain.tld';
$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';
$connection = ssh2_connect($host);
if (ssh2_auth_password($connection, $username, $password)) {
  echo "Authentication Successful!\n";
} else {
  die("Authentication Failed...");
}
if (ssh2_scp_send($connection, '/local/filename', '/remote/filename')) {
  die("Upload Successful!\n");
} else {
  die("Upload Failed...");
}
```

Or you can check out [this](http://maanasroyy.wordpress.com/2012/05/24/curl-sftp-from-php/) tutorial if you still prefer curl.