# stop executing loop after a selected time

Tags: php, loops

I wanna stop executing loop after a selected time. Means when looping it will try to execute an argument and take a long time then it will finish working and go to next argument. such as :

```
for ($i=2 ; $i <= 100 ; $i++)
```

Here, suppose it will loop 3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 and in 11 it will take a long time to execute. So i just wanna stop it after ( i.e 10 seconds ) and take next option i mean 12,13,14... etc. 
So, how can i do this. I set up this `set_time_limit(10);` , but it is not working here.

Comment: related to http://stackoverflow.com/q/10587323/1689451

Answer (score 3):

You can use [microtime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php) to measure time elapsed. Note that this will only break after an iteration has completed.

```
$start = microtime(true);
$limit = 10;  // Seconds

for ($i=2 ; $i <= 100 ; $i++) {
  if (microtime(true) - $start >= $limit) {
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: it will check at start of iteration but probably he want a solution to break the loop during the iteration.

Comment: may be it will break my whole script if i put it globally ? 
@mansoor , ya right .

Comment: @mansoor That's what I meant with "Note that this will only break after an iteration has completed". Can't come up with a scenario where this is *not* what you want

Answer (score 1):

That is quite complex. You will have to create a separate thread to do the processing in, so your main thread can check if it has been running for too long.

Those threads are called 'forks' in PHP.

You'll have to investigate the [Process Control functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pcntl.php) and especially `[pcntl_fork][2]`. Then, using [pcntl_sigtimedwait](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-sigtimedwait.php), you can wait for the forked process during a given timeout. When `pcntl_sigtimedwait` returns, you can check its returned value to see if the process timed out.

Comment: Yes. 'Thread' may not be the right term. However, as I showed, there are ways to fork the process and run the forked child process in parallel with the (waiting) main process.

Comment: probably here `OS forks` can be used.

Comment: Yes, that's what those PHP functions use in the background.