# How to setup phpunit tests for a php daemon

Tags: php, mocking, phpunit

I'm quite new to PHPUnit, and need some advice on how to properly test this `Daemon` class, `start()` and `runTask()` methods.

```
class Daemon {
    public function start() {
        // Start the loop
        while (true) {
            // This is the code you want to loop during the service...
            $this->runTask();

            // If signaled to stop
            if ('stop' == $this->sig) {
                // Break the loop
                break;
            }

            // Now before we 'Task' again, we'll sleep for a bit...
            usleep($this->delay);
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried to use a mock, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
$mock = $this->getMock('Daemon');
$mock->expects($this->once())->method('runTask');
$mock->start();
```

Comment: I think in this case, you would just test the `runTask()` method and not test the `start()` method.

Answer (score 1):

I would try setting `$this->sig` to `stop` before testing the method, allowing it to only run once. You should mainly be concerned about testing `$this->runTask()`, but I understand wanting better coverage, and testing the `break;` logic.

The problem is, if the "stop logic" fails, your tests might run forever, so you'll need to set a timelimit for the test suite (see [PHPUnit Strict Mode](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/strict-mode.html)). Timing-out a function call is difficult in PHP (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10587323/timeout-a-function-in-php)), and may need to involve spinning-off a subprocess, but this could be done as well. Try to do as little as possible inside the while loop (even the stop check could be refactored out to a `if ($this->shouldStop()) break;`, then just test `$this->shouldStop()` and `$this->runTask()`.