# How to check if execution of script exceeds x seconds?

Tags: php

I have a PHP script that uses an API. Sometimes the API can be fast, sometimes it’s slow. Is there a way to check if execution time of the get_contents(); is above ex. 2 seconds?

If it goes over this amount i want the included script to stop, and execute the original file.

Ex:

```
<?php 

    include("file.php"); //if more than 2 sec, continue

    echo "Hello world";

?>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Comment: Your title and your question are asking two different things ("skip" vs. "check"). Please be clearer in what it is you are asking.

Comment: this answer here [Timeout a function in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10587359/2359679) maybe answer your question.

Comment: You keep changing the underlying question.  The goal of this post is unclear, and the unclearness is evolving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `set_time_limit` function to set the maximum time limit

```
.... //some logic
const MAX_EXECUTION_TIME = 2; // for 2 seconds
set_time_limit(self::MAX_EXECUTION_TIME);
file_get_contents(...);
.... // some other logic
```

Comment: using `set_time_limit` will throw an error if the execution time is greater than the time you've set !

Comment: `Set the number of seconds a script is allowed to run. If this is reached, the script returns a fatal error.`

Comment: You're right. Maybe a try catch block would work? Or a better alternative could be to use curl. So something like `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 2)` should do the trick

Comment: I'm sorry I misinterpreted the OP's question. As far as I know, there is no way of knowing the execution time of a script beforehand as it depends on a lot of variable factors like server speed for eg

Comment: there is another important point, that `set_time_limit` is set the time limit for the whole script, not only part of it.

Comment: Sorry I had to downvote, but it is fundamentally wrong, since time spent to make an http request is not counted towards script time limit.