# Stop PHP function after a certain time limit

Tags: php, oracle, web-services

I am developing a web service where I need to call an Oracle procedure in PHP. The Oracle procedure will take time to process and after completion it will write in a table.

How do I return an error in the web service response if the procedure call is taking too much time?

Note: I am stuck with PHP 5.2 and I cannot install cURL.

Comment: php has a default time limit of 30 for entire script execution, is this enough? you can also modify it per script if you haven't disabled that functionality.. http://php.net/set_time_limit

Comment: You can set the general time limit with set_time_limit(); A more specific solution may be found in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10587323/timeout-a-function-in-php - I guess you can manage it by utilising the pcntl_alarm() function.

Comment: You cannot catch a max execution time error. The scripts just stops as well as all processing that follows. I need to return something, like a message if it happens.

Comment: A combination of a user profile in the DB and sqlnet.ora parameters like recv_timeout are the best way.  PHP's max_execution time is the time used for PHP code, and doesn't/didn't get checked when calls are waiting for the DB.

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider using http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php ?

**Sets the number of seconds a script is allowed to run. If this is reached, the script returns a fatal error. The default limit is 30 seconds or, if it exists, the max_execution_time value defined in the php.ini.**

You can set it for your specific script for less than 30s, so it stops after e.g. a few seconds. And then you just handle empty response / error response.

Answer (score 0):

In php.ini default execution time limit is 30 seconds... Customise it & write your code in try catch & handle exception with customise error message.