# How can I write a file txt in another PC by using PHP?

Tags: php, linux

I'm trying to write a file text from PHP file and save it in another PC in the same network, so that is what I write :

```
$myfile = fopen("192.168.100.18/file.txt", "w") or die("Error!");
```

so I got an error message, what should I do ?

** note: I'm using Linux for both PCs

Comment: Better (if the second PC as php too) create a php script on the second PC that get the data and save it local. Or use FTP read more here Example#2 http://php.net/manual/en/features.remote-files.php

Comment: is another pc is FTP server

Comment: More http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140318/php-write-to-file-on-different-server

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you need to call a script on the other pc, so the URL would be like this:

PHP on the request side:

```
<?php

file_get_contents("192.168.100.18/save-file.php");

?>
```

PHP on the recipient side:

Create a file at the root called save-file.php and set the contents of the file to the following script:

```
<?php

file_put_contents("file.txt", "some string");

?>
```

This way, every time you will load the script on the first pc it will request the save-file.php script on the other pc which in turn will save the file.

Comment: Thank you, I did that but unfortunately it didn't work, writing the path in this way `ip/filename` doesn't work