# Send files from LAMP stack to Windows SFTP server via PHP

Tags: php, ssh, lamp, sftp

I'm having a good deal of trouble sending a file from a linux server to a windows server over SFTP via PHP.
I seem to be connecting just fine, but it always throws an error that I can't create the file on the remote server's end.  It's possible that I am messing up at the syntax for the file location.

I have tried two ways now, one using `ssh2_scp_send()`, and another trying 
`fopen(ssh2.sftp://D:/path/file.csv)`

Also, logging into the sftp server via a client puts me at my home folder (ie D:\path\to\home) but if I do a 
`ssh2_exec($connection, 'cd');`
and print the stream to the screen, it shows me that my ssh session is currently in the windows filesystem on the C drive.

I was hoping someone would have some advice on this.  And I'm not married to this method.  I'm using php on my end because it's all coming from a drupal module, but I could always try and incorporate another method.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/717854/sftp-from-within-php

Comment: Have you looked at CURL? It has the ability to send via SFTP.

Comment: I haven't yet, but that's my next plan.  I'm just hoping that I'm getting the path correct for the remote windows server.  Im not familiar with formatting it for windows, and if I need to include the drive in the path, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is send one file, curl works, I suppose, but if you want to do anything more - like maybe verifying that the file has been uploaded, upload multiple files, use publickey authentication, or whatever, curl just isn't versatile enough for that.

My recommendation would be to use [phpseclib, a pure PHP SFTP implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 0):

CURL can use th sftp library.

```
$localfile = 'test.txt';
  $ch = curl_init();
  $fp = fopen ($localfile, "r") or die('Cannot open textfile');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"sftp://123.123.123.123:10022/username/test.txt");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "username:password");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fp);
  if(curl_exec($ch)){
    echo 'File was successfully transferred using SFTP';
  }else{
    echo 'File was unable to be transferred using SFTP';
  }

  curl_close ($ch);
```