# Is there an SFTP library for CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, sftp

I know there is a default FTP Library Class, but it doesn't work with SFTP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally, I'd recommend [phpseclib, a pure PHP SFTP implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/).  It has no external dependancies, unlike the PHP ssh2 library extension Femi recommended and it's a ton more versatile than cURL.

Answer (score 3):

If you download phpseclib, you can put it in the `third_party` folder and create a simple library using :

```
    set_include_path(APPPATH . '/third_party/phpsec');
require_once APPPATH."/third_party/phpsec/Net/SFTP.php"; 
class Sftp {  }
```

Which then it's just like all other libraries that you can use wherever in your Codeigniter app.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/156139/. It uses the PHP ssh2 library extension (see http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-sftp.php, with the overview at http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.ssh2.php).

Or do it with cURL: previously mentioned at [SFTP from within PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/717854/sftp-from-within-php).

But no, there is no CI class library that does SFTP.