# cURL- listing FTP directory contents, or downloading the entire directory

Tags: php, curl, ftp

Using CURL and connecting by FTP, how do I  list the contents of a remote directory? Instead of downloading a single file individually and having to know the filename, I have a requirement to download the whole remote directory (which will just be a bunch of text files).

Is there any way using FTP with cURL to either:

1. Download all files in a directory
2. List all files in a directory, so I can iterate over these and download.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/717854/sftp-from-within-php might help ..

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have to use cURL, [try this guy.](http://php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php). It looks like this closer to what you are looking for!

Comment: Yes I did see that, although I am tossing up whether to use cURL or native functions, as I have a few other protocols I will be using (SFTP and SCP). Are there similar libraries in PHP for these two?

Comment: If you need to SFTP and SCP, I'd probably just stick with cURL. I know they have built in functionality for those two protocols, so I think you'll be best off with that. Lemme know how it works out!

Comment: I ended up going with cURL.. quite successfully! Thankyou