# How to upload file with curl on sftp server

Tags: php, curl

This code

```
$user = 'user';
$pass = 'password';
$filename = 'text.txt';
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$ch = curl_init();
$localfile = 'text.txt';
$fp = fopen($localfile, 'r');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'sftp://$user:$pass@myserver.com/upload/$filename');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS, CURLPROTO_SFTP);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, filesize($localfile));
curl_exec ($ch);
$error_no = curl_errno($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
if ($error_no == 0) {
        $error = 'File uploaded succesfully.';
} else {
        $error = 'File upload error.';
}
echo $error.' '.$error_no;
```

gives me this error:

> File upload error. 7 ( Failed to write file to disk )

My requirement is simple, I just need to upload `text.txt` file on live server using curl.

Comment: Well, are you able to upload the file from the same server using the same credentials with the command line sftp utility? Because this looks like a server issue...

Comment: Have you tried using `CURLOPT_VERBOSE => 1`?

Comment: There are a lot of answers here, but I don't see a solution using ssh2 or cURL sFTP, an encrypted or unencrypted private key, and a solution that is tested and that works. It seems that no one who has accomplished a file upload in sFTP in PHP code has shared their code. Even the PHP Manual seems to have no working example that uploads a file securely.

Answer (score 2):

So for diagnosing SSH / SFTP problems I think [phpseclib, a pure PHP SFTP implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/index.html), is the best approach. Here's how:

```
<?php
include('Net/SFTP.php');

define('NET_SFTP_LOGGING', NET_SFTP_LOG_COMPLEX);

$sftp = new Net_SFTP('www.domain.tld');
if (!$sftp->login('username', 'password')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

$sftp->put('text.txt', 'text.txt', NET_SFTP_LOCAL_FILE);

echo $sftp->getSFTPLog();
?>
```

In particular, what's useful about phpseclib is it's ability to create log files so you can see what's going on.

I think it's easier to use, too, lol, but that's up to you.

Comment: any suggestions on how to install and use phpseclib. Ive tried multiple ways and cannot get it to function correctly

Comment: @Beanno1116 - you should post that as a new question. Use phpseclib, composer and php as the tags

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/717854/sftp-from-within-php?rq=1) can help you,

There are some examples of different ways to upload files using CURL.

or try this

```php
$localfile = 'sample.txt';
$user      = 'user';
$password  = 'pass';
$host      = 'ftp.remote.com';

$ch = curl_init();
$fp = fopen($localfile, 'r');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "sftp://{$user}:{$password}@{$host}/{$localfile}");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS, CURLPROTO_SFTP);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, filesize($localfile));
curl_exec ($ch);

$error_no = curl_errno($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

if ($error_no == 0) {
    $error = 'File uploaded succesfully.';
} else {
    $error = 'File upload error.';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Answers to this question helped me today.

I just want to point out that your vars in `'sftp://$user:$pass@myserver.com/upload/$filename'` will never get interpreted since you're using single quotes. You should either use double quotes or concatenate your vars to single quoted strings.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the problem that your script, that I used as starting point, didn`t work. So I just set the CURLOPT_VERBOSE and added curl_error result to the output. This way, I realized, that curl had no ssh support enabled in my case, which I could solve by re-emerging (=re-building on other systems, I am on gentoo) with ssh support. Also the single-quotes in your code prevent correct variable substitution.
After solving those problems, and few typos, my result with your function, using my test-credentials and host, looks like this now :

- Trying ...
- TCP_NODELAY set
- Connected to  () port 22 (#0)
- SSH MD5 fingerprint: 4dbea14faf74ee128d5874017332f4ef
- SSH authentication methods available: publickey,keyboard-interactive
- Using SSH private key file '/root/.ssh/id_rsa'
- SSH public key authentication failed: Username/PublicKey combination invalid
- Failure connecting to agent
- Initialized keyboard interactive authentication
- Authentication complete
- We are completely uploaded and fine
- Connection #0 to host  left intact
- Closing connection 0

File uploaded successfully. 0

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if you ever got yours  working but I used some of your code to get mine working.

I found I needed to use `CURLOPT_USERPWD` and take user and password out of the url.  But in my search for an answer I also found someone that need to do the opposite, get rid of the CURLOPT_USERPWD, and put them in the url.  That may be server dependent.

If I were at the point of your post I would add the `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);`.
Then when I got it working I would remove it if you feel an absolute need for the finger print. 
The last 4 curl_setopt's are only for trouble shooting.

This code has been tested on two different SFTP servers.
Once is a GoDaddy VPS, CentOS 7 box, the other a GoAnywhere server.

```
$host = 'xx.xxx.xxx.xxx/server/public_html';
$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';
$localfile = "/home/server/public_html/xxx/resultTest.txt";
$fp = fopen($localfile, 'r');
$url = "sftp://@$host";
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS, CURLPROTO_SFTP);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, filesize($localfile));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch); 
$error = curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```